# Why is CSS not rendering in chrome but is working in Eclipse?

Tags: css, jsf

I'm using JSF for the front end of my application. CSS is rendering correctly inside Eclipse but is not working in chrome browser. Here is how I have called the CSS file in JSF. Can anyone tell me what the problem is. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"

<h:head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"  />
```

Comment: Did you try to clean chromes' cookies? Often it works after that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. CTRL+F5 did the job! If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Chrome is *caching* the CSS resources - so only an old stale version is used.

While resource cache control should be configured appropriately for live deployment, one can quickly perform a ["force refresh"](https://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome) in Chrome but pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (or Ctrl+Shift+R) in Windows and Cmd+Shift+R in OS X.

Alternatively, [the cache control can be configured from the Chrome Developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development).

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem from time to time.

Rather than hitting F5, I manually click the refresh, and it usually works. Firefox could also be helpful at that point.